# JavaCV error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

Tags: android, javacv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am now developing an Android app with JavaCv 1.0 from github.com/bytedeco/javacv. I use JavaCv to grab frames of mp4 video.

It works well on Sony Z2 (5.1.1), redMi HM 2A (4.4.4), HM NOTE 1S CU (4.4.4) and other devices, however on MI Note Pro (5.1.1), HuaWei TIT-AL00 (5.1), it reports error as the [snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jiF9.png).

build.gradle file of video module is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIzL1.png).

Could anyone please tell me what I should do to resolve this issue? Great thanks!

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42102181/5963700

Comment: Thanks! After checking all dependencies in my project, I found out that the issue was occurred by Fresco. Fresco has library built for 64 bit architecture, and then the system will look for a 64 bit version of each other library. Since JavaCv don't have 64 bit binaries, the system will report error. I think it is similar to this. Hope it will help others!